# Convert this Word DataFrame into Zero One Matrix Format DataFrame in Python Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

Want to convert user_Id and skills dataFrame matrix into zero one DataFrame matrix format user and their corresponding skills

Input DataFrame

```
     user_Id                        skills

0     user1               [java, hdfs, hadoop]
1     user2               [python, c++, c]
2     user3               [hadoop, java, hdfs]
3     user4               [html, java, php]
4     user5               [hadoop, php, hdfs]
```

Desired Output DataFrame

```
user_Id       java  c   c++     hadoop  hdfs    python  html    php     

user1         1     0   0       1       1       0       0       0
user2         0     1   1       0       0       1       0       0
 user3        1     0   0       1       1       0       0       0
user4         1     0   0       0       0       0       1       1
user5         0     0   0       1       1       0       0       1
```

Comment: In column `skills` are `lists` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) new `DataFrame` created by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) if need convert `lists` to `str` (else omit), then remove `[]` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df[['user_Id']].join(df['skills'].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', '))
print (df)
  user_Id  c  c++  hadoop  hdfs  html  java  php  python
0   user1  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
1   user2  1    1       0     0     0     0    0       1
2   user3  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
3   user4  0    0       0     0     1     1    1       0
4   user5  0    0       1     1     0     0    1       0
```

---

```
df1 = df['skills'].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', ')
#if necessary remove ' from columns names
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip("'")
df = pd.concat([df['user_Id'], df1], axis=1)
print (df)
  user_Id  c  c++  hadoop  hdfs  html  java  php  python
0   user1  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
1   user2  1    1       0     0     0     0    0       1
2   user3  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
3   user4  0    0       0     0     1     1    1       0
4   user5  0    0       1     1     0     0    1       0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Its work for me and very optimized solution :)

Comment: What about `df.columns = df.columns.str.encode("utf-8")` ?

Comment: NO,
But this line work for me

`df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip("u'")`

Comment: but same solution not working for this problem  @jezrael 

`user_Id                        skills

0     user1               "java, hdfs, hadoop"
1     user2               "python, c++, c"
2     user3               "hadoop, java, hdfs"
3     user4               "html, java, php"
4     user5               "hadoop, php, hdfs" `

Comment: What is wrong? `df1 = df['skills'].str.get_dummies(', ')` does not works?

Comment: skills are in double quotes " " not in enclosed in brackets [] for that i'm using

`df1 = df['skills'].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', ')`

but its not working

Comment: Hmmm, maybe need `df1 = df['skills'].str.strip('"').str.get_dummies(', ')`

Comment: `df1 = df['skills'].str.get_dummies(', ')`
no its not working


output like that


      c,java,javascript  hadoop,hdfs,java  html,php,python  python,php,c,c++
0                  1                 0                0                 0
1                  0                 0                1                 0
2                  0                 0                0                 1
3                  0                 1                0                 0

Comment: `df1 = df['skills'].str.strip('"').str.get_dummies(', ') ` no i already tried

Comment: Can you create new question or edit this one? Because bad format of comments. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145445/discussion-between-sanjeev-singh-and-jezrael).